# AC side curtains don't fit into the window frame. Am I missing something?

Tags: windows, air-conditioning

[image: The windowframe]

As shown in the picture, the part of my window the side flange at the end of the side curtains is supposed to slip behind is entirely too thick to fit snugly while screwed into the pane above it. Am I missing something, or are these windows just bad for side flaps? Should I even bother continuing to try to install this A/C unit?

EDIT:

[image]

To add a little clarity, the side curtain flange hits the outcropped bit at the edge of the window, where the red arrow points, instead of fitting snugly behind it, where the yellow arrow points.

[image]

Here is a picture of the wing fitting snugly inside the windowframe, which it can only do when the window is not sitting behind the top rail.

Comment: Tried to clarify as best I could. The wings don't fit snugly within the windowframe. Instead, the edges just sort of touch.

Comment: the pictures show the problem clearly now ..... looks like you need some sort of an adapter that goes between the window frame and the top of the curtain .... what happens if you extend the side curtain into the window frame slot and then slide the window down?

Comment: At that point, the top flanges of the curtains (Where it says Right) block the window from lowering to behind the top rail.

Comment: That would give you a better side seal. To help seal the window sash to the top, you could put split foam pipe insulation on top of the curtain.

Comment: Trim the wing on the curtain, or add a piece of pipe foam to the curtain wing.

Comment: Thanks. In the end I decided to pick up some foam to seal it up, rather than trimming the wings.